# How to create pojo file of nested json for getting response with retrofit

Tags: android

How can I create pojo file for nested json to get response with retrofit. Follwing are my json.

```
{
        "Category_Name": [
            "Breads",
            "Combo and Thali",
            "Main Course",
            "Rice and Biryani"
        ],
        "Alldishitems": [
            [
                {
                    "Subcategory": "Brown bread",
                    "DishName": "Stuffed Paratha",
                    "DishPrice": "100",
                    "Dishquantity": "10",
                    "Dishdescription": ""
                },
                {
                    "Subcategory": "white Bread",
                    "DishName": "Plain Paratha",
                    "DishPrice": "136",
                    "Dishquantity": "10",
                    "Dishdescription": ""
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "Subcategory": "Combo",
                    "DishName": "Rajma Masala Combo",
                    "DishPrice": "136",
                    "Dishquantity": "10",
                    "Dishdescription": ""
                },
                {
                    "Subcategory": "Combo",
                    "DishName": "Lassi with Aloo Paratha",
                    "DishPrice": "100",
                    "Dishquantity": "10",
                    "Dishdescription": ""
                },
                {
                    "Subcategory": "Thali",
                    "DishName": "Chinise thali",
                    "DishPrice": "100",
                    "Dishquantity": "10",
                    "Dishdescription": ""
                }
            ],
    ]
```

Follwing code I have tried but getting null

```
public class ServerResponse {
    @SerializedName("Category_Name")
    String[] Category_Name;
    @SerializedName("Alldishitems")
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Getmenulist>>getmenudata = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<Getmenulist>>();

    public  ServerResponse(String[] category_Name,ArrayList<ArrayList<Getmenulist>> getmenudata)
    {
        this.Category_Name=category_Name;
        this.getmenudata=getmenudata;
    }

    public String[] getCategory_Name() {
        return Category_Name;
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Getmenulist>>getGetmenudata() {
        return getmenudata;
    }
}

public class Getmenulist {
    @SerializedName("Alldishitems")
    List<Getmenulist.Getmenudata> data;
    public Getmenulist(List<Getmenulist.Getmenudata> data)
    {
        this.data=data;
    }

    public List<Getmenulist.Getmenudata> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public class Getmenudata {
        @SerializedName("Subcategory")
        String Subcategory;
        @SerializedName("DishName")
        String DishName;
        @SerializedName("DishPrice")
        String DishPrice;
        @SerializedName("Dishquantity")
        String dishQuantities;
        @SerializedName("Dishdescription")
        String Dishdescription;
        @SerializedName("image")
        String image;


        public Getmenudata(String Subcategory, String DishName, String DishPrice, String dishQuantities, String Dishdescription, String image) {
            this.Subcategory = Subcategory;
            this.DishName = DishName;
            this.DishPrice = DishPrice;
            this.dishQuantities = dishQuantities;
            this.Dishdescription = Dishdescription;
            this.image = image;

        }

        public String getDishdescription() {
            return Dishdescription;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getDishName() {
            return DishName;
        }

        public String getDishPrice() {
            return DishPrice;
        }

        public String getDishQuantities() {
            return dishQuantities;
        }

        public String getSubcategory() {
            return Subcategory;
        }

    }
}
```

Above code I have tried but getting null.I got the size of array but there is   not data in that.and if your dont mind please help me to get out this problem.
do I need to change json or pojo file. I am trying to fetch data for sticky list. My data like Category then subcategory and after that list of that data.

Comment: you can use this to generate http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Your JSON is not proper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Use http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ for creating model class directly from your JSON. Have a look once. It will help you forever

Answer (score 0):

the error is in ServerResponse class, getmenudata is not a arraylist< arrayList<...>> because there's already a list in Germenulist class
try:

```
public class ServerResponse {
    @SerializedName("Category_Name")
    String[] Category_Name;
    @SerializedName("Alldishitems")
    List<Getmenulist> getmenudata = new ArrayList<Getmenulist>();

    public ServerResponse(String[] category_Name, ArrayList<Getmenulist> getmenudata) {
        this.Category_Name = category_Name;
        this.getmenudata = getmenudata;
    }

    public String[] getCategory_Name() {
        return Category_Name;
    }

    public List<Getmenulist> getGetmenudata() {
        return getmenudata;
    }


}

public class Getmenulist {

    @SerializedName("Alldishitems")
    List<Getmenudata> data;

    public Getmenulist(List<Getmenulist.Getmenudata> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public class Getmenudata {
        @SerializedName("Subcategory")
        String Subcategory;
        @SerializedName("DishName")
        String DishName;
        @SerializedName("DishPrice")
        String DishPrice;
        @SerializedName("Dishquantity")
        String dishQuantities;
        @SerializedName("Dishdescription")
        String Dishdescription;
        @SerializedName("image")
        String image;


        public Getmenudata(String Subcategory, String DishName, String DishPrice, String dishQuantities, String Dishdescription, String image) {
            this.Subcategory = Subcategory;
            this.DishName = DishName;
            this.DishPrice = DishPrice;
            this.dishQuantities = dishQuantities;
            this.Dishdescription = Dishdescription;
            this.image = image;

        }

        public String getDishdescription() {
            return Dishdescription;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getDishName() {
            return DishName;
        }

        public String getDishPrice() {
            return DishPrice;
        }

        public String getDishQuantities() {
            return dishQuantities;
        }

        public String getSubcategory() {
            return Subcategory;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. your json format is wrong. here is the updated json:**

```
{ 
   "Category_Name":[ 
      "Breads",
      "Combo and Thali",
      "Main Course",
      "Rice and Biryani"
   ],
   "Alldishitems":[ 
      [ 
         { 
            "Subcategory":"Brown bread",
            "DishName":"Stuffed Paratha",
            "DishPrice":"100",
            "Dishquantity":"10",
            "Dishdescription":""
         },
         { 
            "Subcategory":"white Bread",
            "DishName":"Plain Paratha",
            "DishPrice":"136",
            "Dishquantity":"10",
            "Dishdescription":""
         }
      ],
      [ 
         { 
            "Subcategory":"Combo",
            "DishName":"Rajma Masala Combo",
            "DishPrice":"136",
            "Dishquantity":"10",
            "Dishdescription":""
         },
         { 
            "Subcategory":"Combo",
            "DishName":"Lassi with Aloo Paratha",
            "DishPrice":"100",
            "Dishquantity":"10",
            "Dishdescription":""
         },
         { 
            "Subcategory":"Thali",
            "DishName":"Chinise thali",
            "DishPrice":"100",
            "Dishquantity":"10",
            "Dishdescription":""
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

**2. There should be two classes for this Json file :**

> 1. YourName.java

```
public class PojoClass
{
    private String[] Category_Name;

    private Alldishitems[][] Alldishitems;

    public String[] getCategory_Name ()
    {
        return Category_Name;
    }

    public void setCategory_Name (String[] Category_Name)
    {
        this.Category_Name = Category_Name;
    }

    public Alldishitems[][] getAlldishitems ()
    {
        return Alldishitems;
    }

    public void setAlldishitems (Alldishitems[][] Alldishitems)
    {
        this.Alldishitems = Alldishitems;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Category_Name = "+Category_Name+", Alldishitems = "+Alldishitems+"]";
    }
}
```

> 2. Allitems.java

```
public class Alldishitems
{
    private String Subcategory;

    private String DishPrice;

    private String Dishquantity;

    private String Dishdescription;

    private String DishName;

    public String getSubcategory ()
    {
        return Subcategory;
    }

    public void setSubcategory (String Subcategory)
    {
        this.Subcategory = Subcategory;
    }

    public String getDishPrice ()
    {
        return DishPrice;
    }

    public void setDishPrice (String DishPrice)
    {
        this.DishPrice = DishPrice;
    }

    public String getDishquantity ()
    {
        return Dishquantity;
    }

    public void setDishquantity (String Dishquantity)
    {
        this.Dishquantity = Dishquantity;
    }

    public String getDishdescription ()
    {
        return Dishdescription;
    }

    public void setDishdescription (String Dishdescription)
    {
        this.Dishdescription = Dishdescription;
    }

    public String getDishName ()
    {
        return DishName;
    }

    public void setDishName (String DishName)
    {
        this.DishName = DishName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Subcategory = "+Subcategory+", DishPrice = "+DishPrice+", Dishquantity = "+Dishquantity+", Dishdescription = "+Dishdescription+", DishName = "+DishName+"]";
    }
}
```

*Note* : Remove unnecessary things from code.

Hope this will help you. cheers.